# What are the standard ways to debug RTOS embedded systems?

Tags: rtos

I have only recently started looking into RTOS. I have become aware of existence of FreeRTOS and ThreadX. While the basic theory makes sense, I am getting a bit ahead of myself in my head and getting concerned about how these things are going to be debugged.

From what I know, putting in a breakpoint will cause the program to crash since the program will stop and RTOS can't be stopped. Using things like printf can take a lot of time and with RTOS, it might be bad idea to use this since it will interfere with the timing.

I would be grateful if someone could enlighten me on the standard techniques to debug RTOS systems. We would have to debug things like inter-thread communication, thread getting stuck, etc., which may happen only sometimes and only under real world circumstances. If I can't put breakpoints and can't simulate it, how are these things debugged? Is it really as painful as I think it is?

Comment: If you have a GPIO port connected to some LEDs you can add visual indications of interesting conditions with a single write to that port, rather than slow printf.

Comment: An RTOS, like FreeRTOS or ThreadX (technically known as "AzureRTOS" these days) *can* be stopped. It's just code running on the micro - and there's nothing special about that code. You can put breakpoints wherever you like in your own task code running under the RTOS, or in the RTOS code itself.

Comment: The question is based on assumption that you can't have breakpoints in code that runs under an RTOS. I routinely use breakpoints debugging code that runs under an RTOS and haven't yet been able to crash anything due to it. So it must be possible.

Comment: As far as I know, a breakpoint would stop the program execution. This means that all the threads would be paused. Isn't this supposed to be a problem?

Comment: No standard methodology.  Trial and error approach.  And yes, it can be as painful as it sounds.  Some issues can be caught by breakpoints, while some need real time access like profiling with LEDs.  Ultimately, you need to find something (stress system) to cause bug.   With the really agravating bugs, adding something to debug, changes something just enough to not cause the bug!

Answer (score 1):

A breakpoint suspends the processor (assuming arm cortex m) so the system won’t crash. Breakpoints are normally done at a hardware level. Some systems have options as to whether timers etc stop along with the breakpoint. If you’re debugging pwm motor controllers, you don’t want that to stop when you hit a breakpoint.

As for more advanced debugging, some ide have plugins that give you info on what the current state of the rtos is in regards to the stack levels and task/queue/mutex/etc status.
Debugging any system may involve techniques other than just using a jtag/swd debugger. A serial console is a very powerful tool as is flashing leds etc.